# How to build war from github and deploy into Wildfly using docker? Is it possible?

Tags: docker

I am trying to build war from this and deploy into jboss https://github.com/tongueroo/demo-java

my docker file

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin#70365 --silent
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0
CMD ["git clone https://github.com/tongueroo/demo-java"]
CMD ["cd docker-tomcat-java-example"]
CMD ["./gradlew build"]
```

but I don't know what I should do next, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way would be to build you war before the building your docker images, then use the COPY operator from Dockerfile to put the war in the deployment folder of you wildfly. Something like that:

`COPY  /build/libs/foo.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/`

This would probably be much more cleaner, and can be easily achieved using CI.

If you really need to do it in your docker file (and I think you don't), you should use RUN command before you CMD, install git and gradle then clone and build. Something like that...

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
// RUN Install git here
// RUN Install gradle here

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin#70365 --silent
RUN git clone https://github.com/tongueroo/demo-java
RUN cd docker-tomcat-java-example
RUN ./gradlew build

// Copy the generated war file to the deployment file of your wildfly.

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0
```

Then again, this is too much for me for a docker file and this logic should be ported to continuous integretion, but it should be possible in theory